# how to retrive User name/login name from gmail?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am using google login for custom website. here i wrote the code for it

```
var sOAuthServiceEndPoint = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=http://gdata.youtube.com https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&response_type=token&";
var sOAuthRedirectURL = "http://example.com/testpage/test.html";
var termsAndCondURL = "termsandcondition.html";
var sOAuthClientID = "294016263542.apps.googleusercontent.com"; 
var sAuthenticationURL = sOAuthServiceEndPoint + "redirect_uri=" + sOAuthRedirectURL + "&client_id=" + sOAuthClientID;
```

even i got an access token using below function

```
    function fnOnLoad() {
      //alert("Form Loaded");
      var sAccessToken = '';
      var params = {}, queryString = location.hash.substring(1),regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
      while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
            params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
        }
        if(params.error){
            if(params.error == "access_denied"){
                sAccessToken = "access_denied";
                alert(sAccessToken);
            }
        }else{
                sAccessToken = params.access_token;
                alert(sAccessToken);
        }
        window.opener.fnAuthorisationSuccess(sAccessToken);
        window.close();
    }
```

It's working succesfully and redirect into the other page where I want. but my problem is how to retrive user login name..?

I am using javascript for it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Don't you get an access token from which you can query that information?

Comment: Yes i got Access token

Comment: So have you tried using that to pull the account information?

Comment: that's what i dont know how to pull the account information ? please help

Comment: According to the documentation you can find this information here: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={accessToken}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be found in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall).

> After your application acquires an access token and has (if necessary) verified it, you can use that access token when making requests to a Google API. If the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile scope was included in the access token request, then you may use the access token to acquire the user's basic profile information by calling the UserInfo endpoint.
>
> **Endpoint:** `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo`
>
> Returns basic user profile information, including name, userid, gender, birthdate, photo, locale, and timezone. If the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope was present in the request, then the user's email will also be present in the response. If the email has been verified, then there is also a field that indicates the email is a verified address.